# C++ splitting class functions into individual parts

Tags: c++, function, class, split, segment

is there any way to split the class functions into multiple parts?
It has to be done with class functions, because it's handeling data of objects.

I have multiple "segments" like class containing functions of transfering data over Serial Port, segment responsible for saving the data ... and of course many more...

Example of usage:
obj.send(value); // Function in Serial Port segment used in main loop of an application
obj.save(value); // Function in Data Management segment used in main loop of an application

It is the same object and even the Serial Port segment should have access to Data Management segment (internally done by the app and not the user himself).

I am just asking if there's any way to use some type of relationship (inheritance or composition or some other)

Comment: You can call other functions from functions, and member functions can simply call other member functions (no need to explicitly "pass" the `obj` before the `.`) -- maybe give a working example to show your problem ...

Comment: There is a need, because these are devices and I would like to do:  dev.send() and stuff happens in the background. And I want to split the background stuff into sections. Responsible for saving, sending and other stuff. It s more than thousands of lines

Comment: And of course there is an Encrypting section / segment.

Comment: I'm not questioning the need to split up your function. I'm asking for something like a [mre] (also explaining the trouble you have with splitting your function).

Comment: Its not really a trouble. Its just about design and making it easier to read and modify, to just go into that section and change what s needed.

Comment: Sending functiom does saving process in the backround and sending the data from serial port. It also uses functions during encryption

Comment: Functions, functions, and more functions. Not must more anyone can say without an example to work from.

Comment: My guess is you can inheriting many component classes if that's what you were looking for. But like others said, its hard to tell without more specific examples.